# Pickup multiple items at once in Last of Us

Tags: the-last-of-us

I've been watching a Last of Us let's play after I play each section and I've noticed that when he comes upon a number of items in one place, they all get picked up at once. Is there a way to pick up a bunch of stuff at once, or is he just hammering the triangle button?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pick up multiple items at once by holding triangle.

Note: I usually still prefer to pick them up one at a time so I can see exactly what I'm getting. But if you the ability to tell without the little symbols this can save you some time.

Answer (score -2):

Just hammer time the triangle button, or hold it. I think it's safer to **not** break your controller and just hold the button.

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the existing answer from three years ago

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: @Nirav While not technically disallowed, multiple answers that state the same thing are generally frowned upon because SE tries to uphold a "One Question, One Answer" system. Sure, if you feel that there are other things to add that other answers have not yet covered, go for it! But adding an answer that basically says the same thing doesn't add anything for anyone.